# How to capture refreshed iframe url parameters into parent window

Tags: url, iframe, parameters, parent, capture

I have an iframe with a form in it that gets refreshed after submission.

The refreshed iframe url contains success or fail params in it.

How can i capture those values from parent window with js?

Comment: Is the parent window on the same domain as the framed page?

Comment: hi pekka
the first iframe (before submiting) is cross domain.

the refreshed iframe is the same domain (the one i need to capture url params from)